# c# NetworkCredential and System.Net.WebRequest store crypted in code

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, networkcredentials

I have to make web request with a distant server, and of course I have to authentify for each request.
I have a System.Net.WebRequest and I fill it's Credentials with a NetworkCredential.
The problem is, to initialize NetworkCredential I need to put in plain text in my code the credential informations.

```
new NetworkCredential("my username", "my pwd");
```

How can i declare my credentials informations crypted in my code (sha256)?
The thing is, i understand how request generally crypt your informations before sending, and how server store you credential already crypted, so there must be a way for me to directly write crypted credential and "say" to NetworkCredential or WebRequest : "this username and pwd are already crypted", and the server will not try to crypt it before comparing with the one stored in the database.

I have been searching but couldn't find a way or a clue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When Windows machine are connected in same network they are added to a group which allows machines to communicate using same key.   So if you are connecting between to machines in the same network and you have an account on both machines just use Default Credentials instead of Network Credentials so you do not need to use the username and password.

Comment: That's a good proprosion, saddly  can't do that, our API will run on server, the server of our client.

Comment: If you encrypt the credentials then how would the server be able to decrypt?  Your clients can do what I suggested.

Comment: server will encrypt the information you send them. So maybe there was a "protocol" to say to them, the informaiton i'm sending is already encrypted, don't crypt them before comparing with the one your stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no "turn-around".

The "solution" i'm using right now is, there nothing stored in code, when launching the API the client has to provide the user informations.